# Nothing happens when clicking bootstrap dropdown menu. How to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, dropdown

This is my first time using Bootstrap, so thanks in advance for help here. I have a header element with a dropdown menu. However, when I click the dropdown, nothing happens. No errors in the console. Here are some files:

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Journal</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
  <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
  <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

_navigation.html.erb

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <!-- Elements visible all the time -->
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <%= render 'layouts/navigation/header' %>
      </div><!-- col-sm-7 -->

      <!-- Elements collapsed on smaller devices -->
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <%= render 'layouts/navigation/collapsible_elements' %>
      </div><!-- col-sm-5 -->

    </div><!-- row -->
  </div><!-- container -->
</nav>
```

navigation_helper.rb

```
module NavigationHelper
  def collapsible_links_partial_path
    if user_signed_in?
      'layouts/navigation/collapsible_elements/signed_in_links'
    else
      'layouts/navigation/collapsible_elements/non_signed_in_links'
    end
  end
end
```

_signed_in_links.html.erb

```
<li class="dropdown pc-menu">
  <a id="user-settings" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <span id="user-name"><%= current_user.username %></span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li class="mobile-menu">
  <%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_user_registration_path %>
</li>
<li class="mobile-menu">
  <%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
</li>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.1'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.5'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'devise'
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'bootstrap_form'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: When you say "no errors in console", did you check the browser console too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`javascript_pack_tag`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/webpacker/4.3.0/Webpacker/Helper#javascript_pack_tag-instance_method) will render a JavaScript file located in `app/javascript/packs/` ([Webpacker](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/webpacker.html)). In order to render a file in `app/assets/javascripts/` ([Sprockets](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)), you'll need to use [`javascript_include_tag`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/actionview/6.0.4/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper#javascript_include_tag-instance_method).

---

Alternatively, you could install Bootstrap via Webpacker. Instructions for doing this will vary depending on which version of Bootstrap you'd like to use, but here's [a guide on installing Bootstrap 5 via Webpacker](https://bootrails.com/blog/rails-bootstrap-tutorial).

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I had tried it before, but it kept throwing an error. Not this time. :)